# Link a guest order to an existing customer account in magento

Tags: magento

I want to link a guest order to a existing account in Magento.
Does someone know which fields on which tables I have to change to accomplish this?

Is there maybe a easier way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on Magento >= 1.4.1, you can run that in your database :

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order 
   SET customer_id = YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE 
WHERE entity_id = YOUR_ORDER_ID_HERE AND customer_id IS NULL
```

You will also need to upgrade the "grid" table :

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid 
    SET customer_id = YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE 
WHERE entity_id = YOUR_ORDER_ID_HERE AND customer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: If you're on magento 2 this works as well, but the tables are called sales_order and sales_order_grid. Great tip!

Comment: I just wanted to place a note to state that there is no customer_id column in sales_invoice or sales_invoice_grid tables, so no need to worry about those.

Answer (score 8):

This also seem to work..

```
$order_id = 5;  // Your Order ID
$customer_id = 7;  //Customer ID

$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

if($_order->getCustomerId() == NULL){
    $_order->setCustomerId($customer_id);
    $_order->save();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since from backend it's easier to get increment_id from order than entity id i prefer use this the following two queries:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order 
  SET customer_id = YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE, customer_is_guest=0, customer_group_id = YOUR_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID_HERE
  WHERE increment_id = YOUR_INCREMENT_ID_HERE AND customer_id IS NULL

UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid 
  SET customer_id = YOUR_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE, 
  WHERE increment_id = YOUR_INCREMENT_ID_HERE AND customer_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using magento 1.9.0.1 and I use to change following information:
For Table **sales_flat_order**:
 => change **customer_id** from NULL to **new customer_id**
=> **customer_is_guest** to **0**.

Also for Table **sales_flat_order_grid**:
=> change **customer_id** from NULL to **new customer_id**

Following 2 queries will do the job:

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order 
  SET customer_id = (Your_Customer_ID), customer_is_guest=0 
  WHERE entity_id = Your_Order_ID_HERE AND customer_id IS NULL

UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid 
  SET customer_id = Your_Customer_ID 
  WHERE entity_id = Your_Order_ID AND customer_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what R.S posted:

If you want the admin order screen to reflect what group the member is in you need a few more lines:

```
$customer_id = xxxx;  //Customer ID
$order_increment_id = xxxxxxxxx; //Admin order increment id
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_increment_id);

if($_order->getCustomerId() == NULL){
    $_order->setCustomerId($customer_id);
}

if($_order->getCustomerIsGuest() == "1"){
    $_order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
}

if($_order->getCustomerGroupId() == "0"){
    $_order->setCustomerGroupId(1);
}

$_order->save();
```